# Datatables warning: table id=Datatables_Table_0 - Ajax Error Laravel 8

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I used Datatables in laravel and getting above warning message

Here is my Datatable controller

```
class DatatableController extends Controller
{
 public function index(Request $request)\
 {
  if ($request->ajax()) {
  $data = User::select('*');
  return Datatables::of($data)
  ->addIndexColumn()
  ->addColumn('action', function($row){
     $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>';
  return $btn;
  })
  ->rawColumns(['action'])
  ->make(true);

 }
  return view('datatable');
 }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/datatable', [App\Http\Controllers\DatatableController::class, 'index'])->name('datatable.list');
```

Datatable blade

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
ajax: "{{ route('datatable.list') }}",
columns: [
{data: 'id', name: 'id'},
{data: 'name', name: 'name'},
{data: 'email', name: 'email'},
{data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
]

});
});
</script>
```

Where am I doing wrong ? How do I fix this ? my Ajax error messages keep hitting me

Comment: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error,. you can change `{data: 'id', name: 'id'},` to `{data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false},`

Comment: so no need to mention email and name ?